# In an NFA, what if there are no transitions out of an accept state but there are symbols left in the string?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, automata, finite-automata, computation-models

Let's say I have a string 0110 and after 011 I reach an accept state (let's call the accept state "q") in an NFA. However, there is no transition mentioned in the diagram from q for the symbol 0. Does this mean the computation dies, or does this mean that the string is accepted?

Comment: It dies. Check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Recognized_language).

Answer (score 1):

A string is accepted by an NFA if there is a sequence of moves such that it can reach a final state at the **end of the string**.

As you said, assume that for $w=0110$ after reading $011$ we are in a final state (called $q$) and there is no transition like $\delta(q,0)$, this is when we encounter a situation called **dead configuration**. At this point we can't just say the machine stops, because it's not precise.
What we can say here is that no final state can be reached by reading $w$ so the NFA doesn't accept the string.

Answer (score 0):

Finite automatas (either) DFA or NFA, must be process the entire input string.

DFAs will keep track of a **single state** while processing a string. Think of it as a pointer to the *current* state. It will transition (i.e. move that pointer) according to its rules while processing a string. Remember that for a DFA, all states must have a transition for each symbol in the alphabet. Thus, the DFA will have a unique path to the final state after processing the entire input string. If final state is an accepting state after processing the entire input string, the string is accepted; otherwise, it is rejected.

NFAs on the other hand will keep track of a **set of states** while processing a string. Think of it as having a set of pointers to *all possible* states for which the NFA could have transitioned to after processing a certain number of symbols. This allows for the NFA to not have all transitions defined, the inclusion of $\epsilon$ on transitions, and having a symbol on more than one transition out of a state. If the set of states contains an accepting state after processing the entire input string, the string is accepted; otherwise, it is rejected.

Take the following example:

$L = \{0,1\}^*00^+1 + \{0,1\}^*01^+0$. The following NFA accepts this language.

[image]

We can make a chart that shows how the NFA will process an input string. The left column indicates the current set of states (when we start processing we start with `{A}`). The middle column is the set of states possible from the current set of states after processing a `0`, and similarly for the right column with `1`.

```
              0         1
_________ | ________ | _______
{A}       | {A,B,C}    {A}
{A,B,C}   | {A,B,C,D}  {A,C,D}
{A,B,C,D} | {A,B,C,D}  {A,C,D}
{A,C,D}   | {A,B,C,D}  {A,C}
{A,C}     | {A,B,C,D}  {A,C}
```

Suppose we have an input string `001`. The NFA will process the input:

```
0 from {A}       -> {A,B,C}
0 from {A,B,C}   -> {A,B,C,D}
1 from {A,B,C,D} -> {A,C,D}
```

We see that the final set of states is `{A,B,C,D}` which does contain an accepting state. Thus, $001 \in L$. Notices while processing the string, the NFA did not record the way it got to the accepting state; it just records that it is possible to get to one.

Suppose however we have an input string of `0011`. The NFA will process the input:

```
0 from {A}       -> {A,B,C}
0 from {A,B,C}   -> {A,B,C,D}
1 from {A,B,C,D} -> {A,C,D}
1 from {A,C,D}   -> {A,C}
```

We see then that the final set of states is `{A,C}` which does not contain an accepteing state. Thus, $0011 \notin L$.

TL;DR

FAs must process the entire input. For NFAs, if the final set of possible state the machine could end in contains a final state, then the input string is accepted; otherwise, it is rejected.